# Why nothing is displayed in ListView although there are no errors?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I looked for the solutions but i was not able to understand properly that,why it is happening. I tried to put list view in a Linear layout but it didn't helped.C an anyone help me with My list view.

here's my Xml -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_cards"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Card - 1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/crad_color"
        android:textSize="34sp"

        />
</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_icon">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            >


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?actionBarItemBackground">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:text="Yes its there !" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"

                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:text="NO ! its not"

                    />

            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Here's my java code -->

```
package com.example.android.chooseanumber_magicalapp;

import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.attr.id;
import static android.R.id.list;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;
import static com.example.android.chooseanumber_magicalapp.R.id.list_num;

 /**
  * Created by great on 25-05-2017.
*/

public class InstructionActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(30);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.instruction_activity);


    list.add("1");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("1");


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(list_num);
    {
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

 }
```

edit -->

image from android studio[doesn't show anything in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gq2A.png)

Screen shot from mobile -->

EDIT __>

okay guys now i get the problem if i change my style to

```
  <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

it shows list items !

before it was

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

but what if i want a full screen (without action bar)?

Comment: Height of listview parent is 0dp in Lineary layout. make it some hard coded width to test your output.

Comment: there is no issue with list view parent height as weight is given

Comment: Just tried that . But same thing happens!

Comment: are the other components showing on the output?

Comment: check my ans my friend

Comment: yes all components are showing

Comment: I just tried your code. It seems to be working for me. Is this your entire code?

Comment: but its not working in mine i can link images if you want . Can there be some other reason ? @tompee

Comment: Should i try clearing caches and restart ?

Comment: may be consider adding a scroll view in your layout file. i am thinking may be the listview is hidden due to screen size

Comment: You can try to clean and see if that helps you. I was wondering, are you modifying the contents of your list right after you set it in the adapter? If yes, that might be the cause. As long as the list view entries are not displayed, modifying the list will affect the list that will be displayed since they share the same instance.

Comment: Scroll view is not helping

Comment: okay guys now i get the problem if i change my style to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_num);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with listview casting. change following line

```
  ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(list_num);
```

to

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_num);
```

Comment: He has a static import of the id

Comment: if that was the case the compiler should have thrown an exception

Comment: Remove the parenthesis across lv.setAdapter(adapter); as those are redundant

Comment: i think there must be some problem in Xml .

Comment: I don't thing xml has any problem

Comment: Have you tried to clean Project/rebuild project? if still have issue try to restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

changes these line in you code

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_num);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//1. Create arr (data source)
 final String arr[]={"Teo","Ty","Bin","Bo"};
 //2. get listview by id
 ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvperson);
 //3. put the data
 ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
 (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
 //4. put it in listview
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If it doesn't work, test with just the listview only !

Comment: I don't get your problem,
Just:
1. Can't get listview because of id
2. wrong type adapter
Can you give me more detail?

Answer (score 0):

it's working change only findviewbyID(list_item) to findviewbyID(R.id.list_item)[image]

Comment: i edited my question just now. can you please help me?

Comment: visit this:-     http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-make-activity-as-fullscreen-removing-title-bar-or-action-bar/